# Is there a way to change the Font used in the VS2012 Test Output Window?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fonts

I'd like to change the font used in the Test Output window (see picture below) of Visual Studio 2012 (SP3) without changing other windows. I know you can change the font by going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors and changing the Environment Font but this changes for all windows, menus, dialogs etc...

Is there a way of changing the font used in the Test Output window only ?

[image: VS2012 Test Output Window]

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Go to "Tools" → "Options" → "Fonts and Colors" In "Show settings for:".

The `Test Output` text is changed by the "Environment Font" option in the "Show settings for:" dropdown. Unfortunately, this changes the font for all the menu items and tabs as well.

Comment: This also works for Visual Studio 2010, but like 2012 it changes basically all the fonts in VS.

Comment: Also works for Visual Studio 2013, but again, it changes basically all the fonts there too.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and there still doesn't seem to be a better way to do this.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has rating of 6

Answer (score 3):

The "Environment Font" option in *Tools►Options►Fonts and Colors* changes the test output, but also sets the menu and many other items.